# wpf xaml button with AccessText seems not to query CanExecute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

#### Explanation

- **Aim:** In my wpf desktop application I want to add `AccessText` to a button that is bound to a command that has a predicate which evaluates if the window / control is busy and thus enables/disables the button.
- **Status:** The button command works fine and is properly enabled prior to adding `AccessText`. (I'm using MvvmLight for my ICommand support.)
- **Problem:** After adding `AccessText` the command still binds but the `CanExecute` seems to no longer get queried and the button is always enabled. (My ideal solution would be no code-behind just XAML.)

#### Example

**XAML:**

*Working:*

```
<Button Command="{Binding NavToStoresSearchCmd}" Content="Stores" Height="30"/>
```

*Not Working:*

```
<Button Command="{Binding NavToStoresSearchCmd}" Height="30">
    <AccessText>S_tores</AccessText>
</Button>
```

**C# (ViewModel):**

```
public ICommand NavToStoresSearchCmd { get => new RelayCommand(OnNavToStoresSearch, () => IsNotBusy); }
```

*(The code for `IsNotBusy` and the `OnNavToStoresSearch` command work fine, as does `CanExecute` **UNTIL** I add the `AccessText`.)*

Comment: I do not see where you call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`

Comment: Pretty sure `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` is part of MvvmLight. Plus, the fact my code works prior to adding `AccessText` makes me think it is being called ok.

Comment: Does the command actually execute without the AccessText, so if for example you set a breakpoint in OnNavStoresSearch and click the button, does it get hit? Creating a `new RelayCommand` in the getter seems a bit strange to me, I would usually expect that one instance is created in the constructor and then used (and RaiseCanExecuteChanged should be called as said above).

Comment: The problem is not reproduced. Although the inscription on the button is black, but the button is not available and the command is not executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just tested this, it appears to be working as expected.
My code:

**XAML:**

```
<Button Command="{Binding BrowseCommand}">
    <AccessText>_Browse</AccessText>
</Button>
```

**C# (ViewModel):**

In constructor:

```
BrowseCommand = new RelayCommand( BrowseCommandHandler, () => CanBrowse );
```

'CanBrowse' property:

```
private bool _canBrowse;
public bool CanBrowse
{
    get { return _canBrowse; }
    set { _canBrowse = value; BrowseCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); }
}
```

My guess is you're not calling 'RaiseCanExecuteChanged()' on your RelayCommand?

(Edit: Just seen the comments come in before I hit submit. Sorry folks!)

As said in the comments, *RaiseCanExecuteChanged* is needed here. WPF's CommandManager calls CanExecute when it detects UI changes, such binding updates, state changes, etc. It is unreliable. You may have been lucky in your earlier testing in how the CommandManager was reacting for you, but (in my opinion) it's better to explicitly call RaiseCanExecuteChanged when you know it's changed.

(Further edit)
I did a quick bit of searching around and it appears you can get around needing to call 'RaiseCanExecuteChanged' by changing a namespace entry. Change...

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
```

for

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
```

I quickly ripped the 'RaiseCanExecuteChanged()' code out from my test app and shockingly it appears to work.
Maybe I've been doing it wrong all these years...